# android2.1 ListView reference

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i'm making a project and used a ListView in it. I've given it's code as

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</ListView>
```

I would need to work with the above list and i'm unable to refer it with

```
findViewById(@android:id/android/list);
```

even **"R.id"** isn't working.

I should use a OnClickListener().

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4):

the correct way is :

```
getViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't `@android:id/android:list` be `@android:id/list` in his example for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

try this it is useful

```
<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

and

```
findViewById(R.id.list);
```